# Include resource files in other resources

Tags: android

**Use case:**

If you have multiple buttons to design and you want to have different images in them and a background gradient.

**what I have now**

ImageButton with background the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" >
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient
                    android:type="linear"
                    android:startColor="@color/green_yellow"
                    android:endColor="@color/green_mantis" />

            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap
                android:antialias="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/more_button_check_rates_img"/>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
</selector>
```

This is working, but now i want another one with a other bitmap.

**Question**
Can i create three files (1 shape and two buttons) and then include the shape into the two buttons.

something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" >
    <layer-list>
        <include shape="background"> <!-- this line -->
        <item>
            <bitmap
                android:antialias="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/more_button_check_rates_img"/>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to create multiple xml for multiple background button and just set that xml on those button.:)

Comment: The difference is the bitmap on each button. see my updated question.